# TikZ: How to pass default option to pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

Is there a way to pass default options to a `pic`? In the MWE, the option `transform shape` is passed to an instance of a pic. Is it possible to make this option the default for all pics `square` such that one does not need to pass it to all instances?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tikzset{pics/square/.style={code={\fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}}}
\draw (-1,-1) grid (2,2);
\pic {square=green};
\pic[transform shape] {square=red};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you use `\tikzset{pics/square/.code={\fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}}`, the `transform shape` is not needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a key with a style in a *different* path by calling the complete path. The complete path of `transform shape` is `/tikz/transform shape`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.8,
        pics/square/.style={
            /tikz/transform shape,
            code={\fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}
        }
    ]
        \draw (-1,-1) grid (2,2);
        \pic {square=green};
        \pic {square=red};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]